# Convert a word to a number in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, string-formatting

I need to convert some integers to words and back again, ie: 14 to fourteen and fourteen to 14.

To convert an integer to a word, I am using the .spellout property.  Is there a similar method I could apply to a string that would convert it to a numerical value?  There does not seem to be an equivalent StringFormatter method.

```
//opposite of what I am trying to do:
public extension Int {
    public var asWord: String {
        let numberValue = NSNumber(value: self)
        var formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
        return formatter.string(from: numberValue)!
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using the same number formatter with `number(from:)`?

Comment: By the way, when converting strings back to numbers, you might consider setting `isLenient` to `true`. In the absence of that it gets a little picky (e.g. when `isLenient` is at its default value, `false`, “thirty-two” results in 32, but “thirty two” results in 3002 (!); but when `isLenient` is set to `true`, both result in 32).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension method:

```
public extension String {
    func wordToInteger() -> Int? {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
        return  numberFormatter.number(from: self) as? Int
    }
}
```